# A Diophantine equation revisited

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

No integer solution of [this Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/does-the-equation-x4y41-z2-have-a-non-trivial-solution) $$x^4+y^4+1=z^2$$ is known other than the trivial ones.

While I was reading a paper of [Don Zagier](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.243/NewLooksAtOldNumberTheory.pdf), I realized that his idea on the [Euler's sum of powers conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_sum_of_powers_conjecture) might be helpful to solving the equation. He observed that if $$z^4-x^4-y^4=R^2-QS$$where $Q,R,S$ are quadratic homogeneous equation over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $Q=0$ is tangent to $z^4=x^4+y^4$ at four points. Then the parameterization of $Q=0$ proves that $z^4(p,q)-y^4(p,q)-x^4(p,q)$ is a square, where $z,y,x$ are quadratic homogeneous equation of $p,q$.

**Question:** Can the same trick be applied to $x^4+y^4+z^4$? I tried to find a suitable $Q$ but I failed.

Comment: I found $Q$ genus $1$ (didn't check if it has infinitely many rational points but some might have). Probably you don't want this since it doesn't allow parametrization.

Comment: @joro: Yes. If a suitable **quadratic** $Q$ can be found, then it is possible to solve the equation by solving some pell equation. But I failed to find a suitable $Q$ tangent to $x^4+y^4+z^4=0$ at four points.

Comment: I _suspect_ it exists.